# No services listed on Ambari cluster installation

Tags: service, installation, cluster-computing, ambari

I am trying to install HDP with Ambari but on services page of cluster installation, no services are listed.

[image: no services are listed]

I am using a local repository. There is one thing that i suspect: I have runned createrepo command in various directories. Could this have broken the repository and led to this problem? Should I delete all the repodata folders and create a new one? Do you think this can work?

Or do you have any other suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Update: Using another browser or restarting ambari-server did not work.

I've found below exceptions in ambari-server.log file but I did not choose to install with Kerberos authentication. I used existing JDK instead of what Ambari offered (JDK + Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Policy Files)

17 Oca 2017 12:30:14,403  INFO [ambari-client-thread-97] RepoUtil:156 - Found 0 service repos: []
17 Oca 2017 12:30:14,595  INFO [ambari-client-thread-97] RepoUtil:156 - Found 0 service repos: []
17 Oca 2017 12:30:15,525 ERROR [ambari-client-thread-30] ReadHandler:99 - Bad request:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.apache.ambari.server.state.kerberos.KerberosPrincipalType.SERVİCE
at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:238)
at org.apache.ambari.server.state.kerberos.KerberosPrincipalType.valueOf(KerberosPrincipalType.java:24)
at org.apache.ambari.server.state.kerberos.KerberosPrincipalDescriptor.getKerberosPrincipalTypeValue(KerberosPrincipalDescriptor.java:328)
at org.apache.ambari.server.state.kerberos.KerberosPrincipalDescriptor.(KerberosPrincipalDescriptor.java:127)
at org.apache.ambari.server.state.kerberos.KerberosIdentityDescriptor.(KerberosIdentityDescriptor.java:143)
at org.apache.ambari.server.state.kerberos.AbstractKerberosDescriptorContainer.(AbstractKerberosDescriptorContainer.java:132)
at org.apache.ambari.server.state.kerberos.KerberosComponentDescriptor.(KerberosComponentDescriptor.java:95)
at org.apache.ambari.server.state.kerberos.KerberosServiceDescriptor.(KerberosServiceDescriptor.java:156)
at org.apache.ambari.server.state.kerberos.KerberosServiceDescriptor.(KerberosServiceDescriptor.java:121

Comment: I have noticed that there is a localization problem on .toUpperCase() method or something: exception has a Turkish character 'İ'. 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.apache.ambari.server.state.kerberos.KerberosPrincipalType.SERVİCE

Comment: Most probably this happened by converting the word "service" to uppercase.
I couldn't find out why it converted like this.
My locale settings of OS is as following:

[root@bigdev1 ~]# localectl status
   System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: tr
      X11 Layout: tr

Comment: [root@bigdev1 ~]# locale
LANG=en_US.utf8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_US.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_US.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.utf8"
LC_ALL=
[root@bigdev1 ~]# echo $LANG
en_US.utf8
Any comment is appreciated